# How to make program help text automatically pipe through less?

Tags: bash

Just now, `dpkg --help` spit out three pages of output in my face. I was maybe interested in the first ten lines, which show the general usage and most common arguments.

I'd like that, whenever I run a program (any program) with `--help` as the only argument, if the output is longer than `$(tput lines)`, it would automatically get piped through `less`. Is it easily doable in bash?

**Edit:** In the end, the best solution for me was to switch to zsh. Either one of the following snippets in your `~/.zshrc` will do the job; each one has its own tradeoffs:

```
# Modify the input line before it runs
function lessify() {
    if [[ "$BUFFER" =~ " --help$" ]] ; then
        BUFFER="$BUFFER | less -FX"
    fi  
    zle accept-line
}

zle -N lessify_widget lessify
# Bind to the Enter key
bindkey '^M' lessify_widget
```

or

```
# Alias --help ; ignore rest of the line 
alias -g -- --help="--help | less -FX ; true "
```

Also, in researching this question, I've probably wasted more time than this will ever save me. Don't regret it one bit.

Comment: The task easy do in `zsh` by `alias -g` and not too easy in `bash`. May be you'd satisfy with `man dpkg`?

Comment: Not really. a) Not all utilities have manpages; b) `man` always uses `less`, which you'll have to exit - that's one keypress I'd like to avoid; and c) sometime I automatically type `<some_program> --help` just out of habit.

Comment: I will consider switching to zsh, though.

Comment: Aside from checking if the output is longer than a certain treshold, wouldn't alias --help='--help | less' do the trick?

Comment: @TheJustist `alias --help='--help | less -F'` might just possibly work. I'll check it and update this comment, and then you could post this as an answer. ... Edit: No luck. An alias must be the first word of a command.

Comment: Would a script called 'Help' (for example) help you?
Such as `#!/bin/bash <newline> $1 --help | less -F` which you can call as `Help <program>`. Do not know if this works, just a quick idea.

Comment: Agreed with The Justist: can't do this in bash without a function. the zsh global alias idea will work.

Comment: You can get your desired effect with `expect`, but seriously, you should not do this: `expect -c 'spawn bash; interact -- "--help\r" {send -- "--help | less\r"}`

Comment: Personally, I just have `m` set as an alias to `less` (I used to use `more`, hence the `m`) and all I need to do is type `command --help | m` to get what you're after. Is it really worth writing a function for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `bash`, you can do this with the debug features, although it's a pretty fragile solution and very dependent on your environment.

Enable extended debugging (see [the manual for details](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)):

```
shopt -s extdebug
```

Create a helprun function:

```
helprun() {
    if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] && [ "$2" = '--help' ]; then
        "$@" | less -F
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Then trap all commands with it:

```
trap 'helprun $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
```

This will run `helprun <command>` for every command, and if it is a `--help` command, pipe it through `less`, returning 1 so that the command isn't executed (thanks to `extdebug`). If it isn't, it just runs as normal.

There are probably edge cases I haven't handled here...

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method is to write a script which does the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1 --help | less -F
```

Call it `Help` for example, `chmod +x Help` to make it an executable and place it somewhere in your `PATH`, such as `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.
Then everytime you want to list the help of a program, you use `Help <program>` instead of `<program> --help`.