# What is the best way to pipe the output of a command through a pager if (and only if) it is too long?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, less

I'd like to be able to be able to wrap a command so that if its output doesn't fit in a terminal it will be automatically piped through a pager.

Right now I'm using the following shell function (in zsh, under Arch Linux):

```
export LESS="-R"

RET="$($@)"
RET_LINES="$(echo "${RET}" | wc -l)"

if [[ $RET_LINES -ge $LINES ]]; then
  echo "${RET}" | ${PAGER:="less"}
else
  echo "${RET}"
fi
```

but this doesn't really convince me. Is there a better way (in terms of robustness and overhead) to achieve what I want? I'm open to zsh-specific code, too, if it does the job well.

---

*Update:* Since I asked this question I found [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/34530) which provides a somewhat better — if more complicated — solution, which buffers at most `$LINES` lines before piping the output to `less` instead of caching it all. Sadly that's not really satisfying either, because neither solution accounts for long, wrapped lines. For example, if the code above is stored in a function called `pager_wrap`, then

```
pager_wrap echo {1..10000}
```

prints a very long line to stdout instead of piping through a pager.

Comment: Presumably `wc -l` is counting newline characters, but what if the content is all one line, but wraps enough to go off the terminal?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's a good point, but I don't know how to (efficiently) check for long lines. I also don't like the fact that this code is saving the entire output in a variable instead of buffering at most `$LINES` lines, but I don't know how to fix that, either...

Comment: What's the real problem you're trying to solve? Would you, perhaps, be okay with always piping commands through `less` if it quit automatically if the text displayed all on one screen and didn't need any paging, and didn't clear the screen when it quit? You can do that - http://superuser.com/a/106644/67909

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That would be fine, as long as it doesn't mess with any previous terminal output. I thought about piping to `less -F`, but I ditched it because it doesn't print back the piped output. Do you have a better idea? Anyway, I currently have two use-cases: wrapping around `ls -l` and wrapping around `pacman -Ss [foo]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’ve got a solution that’s written for POSIX shell compliance,
but I’ve tested it only in bash,
so I don’t know for sure whether it’s portable. 
And I don’t know zsh, so I have made no attempt to make it zsh-friendly. 
You pipe your command into it;
passing a command as argument(s) to another command
is a bad design<sup>*</sup>.

Of course any solution to this problem needs to know
how many rows and columns the terminal has. 
In the code below, I’ve assumed that you can rely on
the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environment variables (which `less` looks at). 
More reliable methods are:

- use `rows="${LINES:=$(tput lines)}"`
  and `cols="${COLUMNS:=$(tput cols)}"`, as [suggested by A.P.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/245064/80216#comment421528_245321), or
- look at the output from `stty size`. 
  Note that this command must have the terminal as its standard input,
  so, if it’s in a script, and you’re piping into the script,
  you’ll have to say `stty size <&1` (in bash) or `stty size < /dev/tty`. 
  Capturing its output is even more complicated.

The secret ingredient: the `fold` command will break long lines
the way the screen will, so the script can handle long lines correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh
buffer=$(mktemp)
rows="$LINES"
cols="$COLUMNS"
while true
do
      IFS= read -r some_data
      e=$?        # 1 if EOF, 0 if normal, successful read.
      printf "%s" "$some_data" >> "$buffer"
      if [ "$e" = 0 ]
      then
            printf "\n" >> "$buffer"
      fi
      if [ $(fold -w"$cols" "$buffer" | wc -l) -lt "$rows" ]
      then
            if [ "$e" != 0 ]
            then
                  cat "$buffer"
            else
                  continue
            fi
      else
            if [ "$e" != 0 ]
            then
                  "${PAGER:="less"}" < "$buffer"
                  # The above is equivalent to
                  # cat "$buffer"   | "${PAGER:="less"}"
                  # … but that’s a UUOC.
            else
                  cat "$buffer" - | "${PAGER:="less"}"
            fi
      fi
      break
done
rm "$buffer"
```

To use this:

- Put the above into a file; let’s assume you call it `mypager`.
- (Optionally) put it into a directory that’s is your search path;
  e.g., `$HOME/bin`.
- Make it executable by typing `chmod +x mypager`.
- Use it in commands like `ps ax | mypager` or `ls -la | mypager`.
  If you skipped the second step
  (putting the script into a directory that’s is your search path),
  you’ll have to do `ps ax | path_to_mypager/mypager`,
  where *`path_to_mypager`* can be a relative path like “**`.`**”.

---

## <sup>*</sup> Why is passing a command as argument(s) to another command a bad design?

### I. Aesthetics / Conformance to Traditions / Unix Philosophy

[Unix has a philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) of [Do One Thing and Do It Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well). 
For example, if a program is going to display data in a certain way
(as pagers do),
then it shouldn’t also be invoking the mechanism that produces the data. 
That’s what pipes are for.

Not many Unix programs execute user-specified commands or programs. 
Let’s look at some that do:

- The shell, as in `sh -c "command"`
  Well, running user-specified commands is the shell’s *job*;
  it’s the **One Thing** that the shell does. 
  (Of course I am not saying that the shell is a simple program.)
- `env`, `nice`, `nohup`, `setsid`, `su`, and `sudo`. 
  These programs have something in common — they all exist to run a program
  with a modified execution environment<sup>1</sup>. 
  They have to work the way they do,
  because Unix generally doesn’t allow you
  to change the execution environment of another process;
  you have to change your own process, and then `fork` and/or `exec`.
  _______
  <sup>1</sup> I’m using the phrase *execution environment*
  in the broad sense, referring not only to environment variables,
  but also process attributes such as “`nice`” value, UID and GIDs,
  process group, session ID, controlling terminal, open files,
  working directory, `umask` value, `ulimit`s,
  signal dispositions, `alarm` timer, etc.
- Programs that allow a “shell escape”. 
  The only example that springs to mind is `vi`/`vim`,
  although I’m pretty sure that there are others. 
  These are historical artifacts. 
  They predate window systems and even job control;
  if you were editing a file, and you wanted to do something else
  (like look at a directory listing), you would have had to save your file
  and exit from the editor to get back to your shell. 
  Nowadays you can switch to another window,
  or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (or type `:suspend`)
  to get back to your shell while keeping your editor alive,
  so shell escapes are, arguably, obsolete.

I’m not counting programs that execute other (hard-coded) programs
so as to leverage their capabilities rather than duplicate them. 
For example, some programs may execute `diff` or `sort`. 
(For example, there are tales that that early versions of `spell`
used `sort -u` to get a list of the words used in a document,
and then `diff` — or perhaps `comm` — to compare that list
to the dictionary word list and identify which words from the document
were not in the dictionary.)

### II. Timing Issues

The way your script is written, the `RET="$($@)"` line doesn’t complete
until the invoked command completes. 
Therefore, your script cannot begin to display data
until the command that generates it has completed. 
Probably the simplest way to fix that
is to make the data-generating command
separate from the data-displaying program (although there are other ways).

### III. Command History

1. Suppose you run some command
   with output processed by your display filter, and you look at the output,
   and decide that you want to save that output in a file. 
   If you had typed (as a hypothetical example)

   ```
   ps ax | mypager
   ```

   you can then type

   ```
   !:1 > myfile
   ```

   or press <kbd>↑</kbd> and edit the line appropriately. 
   Now, if you had typed

   ```
   mypager "ps ax"
   ```

   you can still go back and edit that command into `ps ax > myfile`,
   but it’s not so straightforward.
2. Or suppose you decide that you want to run `ps uax` next. 
   If you had typed `ps ax | mypager`, you could do

   ```
   !:0 u!:*
   ```

   Again, with `mypager "ps ax"`, it’s still doable, but, arguably, harder.
3. Also, look at the two commands: `ps ax | mypager` and `mypager "ps ax"`. 
   Suppose you run a `history` listing an hour later. 
   ISTM that you’d have to look at `mypager "ps ax"` a little bit harder
   to see what the command being executed is.

### IV. Complex Commands / Quoting

1. `echo {1..10000}` is obviously just an example command;
   `ps ax` isn’t much better. 
   What if you want to do something just a *little* bit more realistic,
   like `ps ax | grep oracle`?  If you type

   ```
   mypager ps ax | grep oracle
   ```

   it will run `mypager ps ax`
   and pipe the output from that through `grep oracle`. 
   So, if the output from `ps ax` is 30 lines long,
   `mypager` will invoke `less`,
   even if the output from `ps ax | grep oracle` is only 3 lines. 
   There are probably examples that will fail in a more dramatic fashion.

   So you have to do what I was showing earlier:

   ```
   mypager "ps ax | grep oracle"
   ```

   But `RET="$($@)"` can’t handle that. 
   There are, of course, ways to handle things like that, but they are discouraged.
2. What if the command line whose output you want to capture
   is even more complicated; e.g.,

   ```
   command1  "arg1"   |   command2  'arg2'  $'arg3'
   ```

   where the arguments contain messy combinations of space, tab,
   `$`, `|`, `\`, `<`, `>`, `*`, `;`, `&`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `` ` ``,
   and maybe even `'` and `"`.  A command like that can be hard enough
   to type directly into the shell correctly.  Now imagine the nightmare
   of having to *quote* it to pass it as an argument to `mypager`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Oddly enough I had to use `rows="${LINES:=$(tput lines)}"` and `cols="${COLUMNS:=$(tput cols)}"`, because the script cannot access either environment variable, even though, say, `echo $LINES` works as expected from the cli. I also commented out the `printf "%s" "$e"` line. I only have a couple of questions left: 1. Could you explain why passing a command as argument(s) to another command is a bad design? I understand that it's better to avoid a fork, but are there other reasons?

Comment: (continued) 2. Why does your script call `fold -w"$cols" "$buffer" | wc -l` each time instead of, say, keeping a running count of `fold -w"$cols" "$some_data" | wc -l`?

Comment: (0) Yeah, sorry about the `printf "%s" "$e"`.  That was just a debug statement that I didn’t intend to post in my answer.  (1) I’ve addressed #1 in the answer.  (2) Well, `fold -w"$cols" "$some_data" | wc -l` wouldn’t work, but I guess I could have done `printf "%s" "$some_data" | fold -w"$cols" | wc -l`, and, frankly, I didn’t think of it.  I believe that my approach is a little simpler, but your idea would be more efficient, especially if `$rows` is big.  (3) Sorry for taking so long to respond; a turkey crossed the road, and I had to find out why.  :-)  ⁠

Comment: No problem. Thanks for taking the time to answer the follow-up questions.

Comment: @G-Man, can you please explain how to use your solution?

Comment: @grundic I updated my answer with an explanation. If you still don’t understand, describe exactly what has you confused.

Comment: @G-Man excellent, thank you!
Looks like I was confused by the title of the question. I was searching for _automatic_ way of pagering output of any command. It could be that I'm wrong, but your solution could be achieved with piping thoruhg `less -FX` command, right? I was searching for something completely automatic, so running `ps aux` would run pager for me. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184445/how-to-make-program-help-text-automatically-pipe-through-less), but it's not generic unfortunately,

Comment: Note that the GNU implementation of `fold` doesn't support multi-byte characters or zero-width or double-width ones. I don't know of any which understands colouring escape sequences (which the OP's `less -R` suggests they may  expect).

Answer (score 5):

That's what the `-F` option of `less` is for, though you'd need to  use the `-X` option as well, otherwise it prints the text to the alternate screen on terminals that have one (which means it would not be readily available once `less` exits). That might change in the future as [there's currently an enhancement request to have -X implied when the text fits on one screen with `-F` (303)](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html#enhance) and [RedHat systems apparently have had a patch for that since 2008](/a/351919) (though it has not made it upstreams yet (as of 2017-09-14, I've just sent a mail to bug-less@gnu.org about that)).

So:

```
cmd | less -RXF
```

If you still wanted to use the alternate screen if the output is too long, that's where you'd need to get fancy (on systems that don't have the RedHat patch mentioned above):

```
page() {
  L=${LINES:-$(tput lines)} C=${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)} \
    perl -Mopen=locale -MText::Tabs -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -e '
      while(<STDIN>) {
        if ($pager) {
          print $pager $_;
        } else {
          chomp(my $line = $_);
          $line =~ s/\e\[[\d;]*m//g;
          $l += 1 + int(mbswidth(expand($line)) / $ENV{C});
          $buf .= $_;
          if ($l > $ENV{L}) {
            open $pager, "|-", "less", "-R", @ARGV or die "pager: $!";
            print $pager $buf;
          }
        }
      }
      print $buf unless $pager;' -- "$@"
}
```

To be used as:

```
cmd | page
```

or

```
page < file
page -S < file...
```

(not `page file`, it's only meant to page stdin).

We're trying to guess the length of the output by stripping the color escape sequences, expanding the tabs and computing the width so we can determine the number of terminal lines to display a given text line.

That should work as long as the output doesn't have other escape sequences or control/ill-encoded characters.

Note also one significant difference from the RedHat patch: for one-screen output, the output doesn't go through the `less` post-processing (like rendering of control characters as `^X` in reverse video, squeezing of empty lines with `-s`...). While that's closer to what it being asked here, that may be less desirable in practice.

You may have to install the Text::CharWidth module which is not one of the standard ones (`libtext-charwidth-perl` package on Debian).

Comment: hmm, on my machine `ls | less -F` automatically uses the alternate screen if the output is too long, and doesn't if it isn't.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @sourcejedi, not for me, not even with the latest 487 version. Do you have a `$LESS` variable with additional options?

Comment: @sourcejedi, see edit  and  [pager "less": --quit-if-one-screen without --no-init](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/200237) and  [less --quit-if-one-screen without --no-init](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/107315) leading to http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/less.git/tree/less-444-Foption.v2.patch. Are you using a RedHat distro?